# Accessing objects inside List<T> by adding them using AddRange

Tags: c#, list, collections

Is there a way to access the objects in the list? like, getting an exact field in a particular object.  For Instance:

```
List<Object> allObjectResult = new List<Object>();
allObjectResult.AddRange(method(ObjectOne.ToArray()));
allObjectResult.AddRange(method(ObjectTwo.ToArray()));
allObjectResult.AddRange(method(ObjectThree.ToArray()));
```

I want to get a particular field in ObjectOne, ObjectTwo and ObjectThree. How am I able to do that?

> **Updated Question**

In List we can access elements position by order. My first attempt in getting the a particular value in an object inside a List works. This is what I did:

Create a new instance of a list:

```
List<Object> objList = new List<Object>();
```

Added data on it:

```
objList.Add(objdata);
```

Use it in a method:

```
Object[] result = binding.method(Object.ToArray());
```

Loop through:

```
for(i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine("objs {0} - {1}", objList[i].Name, result[i].id);
}
```

However, What I want is I have three objects. What I did is added them in a List:

```
List<Object> allObjectResult = new List<Object>();
allObjectResult.AddRange(binding.method(ObjectOneList.ToArray()));
allObjectResult.AddRange(binding.method(ObjectTwoList.ToArray()));
allObjectResult.AddRange(binding.method(ObjectThreeList.ToArray()));
```

I want to do the same thing like what I did in getting a name in an object (*anyway, it's an object within a List*). I want them to access using a loop.

Comment: Have you Googled how to use a List<T>?

Comment: yes! I also tried the GetRange, but that only return int.

Comment: @robertpeter07 IMO - your exampel lacks effort - not necessarily your research. Im not downvoter - but i think it's bit unclear what you are asking. You dont show what you have *tried* in order to access the objects - just that you added them to a list.

Comment: I tried it in a single object and it works, but trying it in more than one object, that were I failed. I'm getting a specific field name in objects, but could not get it. I know when using List you can access element position by order.

Comment: @JensKloster oopss! I realize something that I can do to get my expected result though thanks for telling that.

Comment: @robertpeter07 that information would have been very usefull. If you had added it the your quistion (+ the attempt that failed), maybe you could have avioded the downvotes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select objects of a certain type:

```
foreach (var obj1 in allObjectResult.OfType<ObjectOne>()) {
  Console.WriteLine(obj1.Whatever);
}
```

Check the type dynamically:

```
foreach (var obj in allObjectResult) {
  if (obj is ObjectOne) {
    var obj1 = (ObjectOne)obj;
    Console.WriteLine(obj1.Whatever);
  } // else ...
}
```